# ¿Como puedo pedir un arreglo con el dato de un campo especifico en Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Suponiendo que tengo este arreglo de to dos:

```javascript
db.todos.insertMany([
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "creado: "17/02/2022"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "creado: "22/05/2022"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "creado: "02/07/2022"
  }
]);
```

Necesito obtener como resultado un array con el dato del campo creado:

```javascript
["17/02/2022", "22/05/2022", "02/07/2022"]
```

¿Existe alguna manera de hacerlo directamente con una consulta de mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible omitir campos, mongoose tiene un metodo para esto llamado "select" el cual te excluira el campo seleccionado, ejemplo:

Supongamos que temos este Schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  email: 
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  ,
  password: 
    type: String,
    required: true,
    select: false,
  ,
);
```

Para hacer una colsulta y evitar que nos retorne la password seria asi:

```
User.find().select("-password")
```

esto nos retornara todos los usuarios pero con el campo de password.

Recomiendo tambien esta publicacion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348437/mongoose-select-a-specific-field-with-find

Comment: ¿Eso no es como hacer una proyección?

Comment: No, al final la consulta te retornara un arreglo pero sin los campos especificados, solo tendrías el "creado" el cual contendría la fecha

Comment: Eso es lo mismo que una proyección, al final Mongoose por debajo elimina los datos que MongoDB devuelve, no creo que sea lo que el OP quiere, aunque te ha marcado la respuesta como válida, pero supongo que por desconocimiento de Mongoose. Usar [`select`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) es exactamente igual que usar una proyección en MongoDB. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si el modelo de esa colección se llama `Todos`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
let result = (await Todos.find({}, {_id: 0, creado: 1})).map(x => x.creado);
```

Asi solo te retornara la propiedad `creado`, y luego usando el `map` le dejas solo el valor (sin la propiedad)

Comment: ¿Y no hay manera de hacer una consulta que te entregue los datos directamente sin tener que operarlos por fuera?

Comment: Porque tienes ese requerimiento? necesitas que el mismo mongoDB te genere ese array?

Comment: Si no importa que ese array no contenga datos repetidos, puedes intentar con un `Todos.find().distinct("creado")` que es como el unico método que si retorna un array de valores... pero si los quieres tener todos, ahi si no sabría como hacerlo, y creo que no sería posible

Comment: Tengo ese requierimiento unicamente por temas de eficiencia, ya que estoy trayendo datos que al final descarto con el map y no uso.